# Downloading an entire folder from my server to iPhone

Tags: ftp, nsurlconnection, download

Is it possible to download an entire folder of files from my server to the user's iPhone rather than just one file at a time?

Also, is the NSURLConnection class the way to go?

Also, should I be using an HTTP path or an ftp path? (I've gotten the download of a single file to work with the HTTP, but don't know how to with the ftp or even if I should bother.

I'm trying to implement the StoreKit and I understand that after I get payment verification, it is my responsibility to provide the additional content to the user's iPhone.  That's the part I'm currently stuck on - downloading that content from my server.

The reason for my request is that I must download a large number of files (which is a variable number of files) and it would be vastly easier if I could just specify the path to the folder and download that folder and everything in it intact.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can download zip files and unzip it with [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/)